# Coded UI test fails after specific period of time on its own

Tags: coded-ui-tests

It goes like this: in my test method, I have 3 `Playback.Wait()` calls. Each one is set to 2 minutes. Between those waits, I am doing some stuff here and there, - that stuff works, was tested without those 3 waits and is all OK. As soon as 3 waits are there, test method just exists on its own, somewhere during 2nd wait. There is no call stack, no useful info regarding the cause for test termination, nothing. I am pretty much clueless at the moment what is happening. Elapsed time is always 5 minutes, - no more no less. 
Do you have any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is a setting in your .testsettings file, under Test Timeouts section.  Specifically, "Mark individual test as failed if its execution time exceeds:", and then gives you fields to enter time in hours, minutes, and seconds.  I believe that 5 minutes is the default.  You can increase this to fit your purpose, or just remove it entirely (not reccommended).

[image: View of the Test Settings file to edit timeouts.]

Comment: But where can I find that .testsettings file?

Comment: It's a solutions file.  Should be listed towards the top of your Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.

Comment: If there's no TestSettings file, then you'll have to create one from the Add New Item menu.  Right-click on the solution, go to add -> New Item.  Then, inside the menu, select Test Settings and configure according to your needs.